# What are the x,y bounds for swipe using UiDevice

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

So the documentation for [UiDevice.swipe](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiDevice#swipe) reads:

```
swipe(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, int steps)
```

> Performs a swipe from one coordinate to another using the number of
> steps to determine smoothness and speed.

How do I know what the max values of X and Y are? All I know at the moment is that 0,0 is the top left corner of the screen. Is there a way to programatically get the X,Y bounds of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum is your display size as pixel. e.g If you have a Galaxy A10 which has 720*1520 screen: minX = 0, max X = 720, min Y = 0, , max Y = 1520.
To get the bounds of screen:

If WebApplication(PWA) or Website (Selenium or Appium chrome/ driver):

`driver.get_window_size()`

If appium mobile:

`driver.manage().window().getSize()`

If web view (Native apps with webview):

```
driver.switch_to.context('WEBVIEW_chrome')  # Replace chrome with gecko/safari if needed
driver.get_window_size()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I did it in Espresso:

```
  val uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
  val maxY = uiDevice.displayHeight;
  val maxX = uiDevice.displayWidth;
```